# Reusing datasource

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm tying to use one database call and reuse that data for other controls - without having to do another call. Scenario: I call the books table which returns all the authors and titles. I create an author's list control called list1 to displays all the titles by Shakespeare and a list2 to display titles by Charles Dickens.

```
Void Bindme()
{

string commandText = "Select * from books";

        SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, datasource1);
        datasource1.Open();
        SqlDataReader myReader1 = mycommand.ExecuteReader();


        list1.DataSource = myReader1;
        list1.DataBind();

        list2.DataSource = myReader1;
        list2.DataBind();

        datasource1.Close();
}
```

In my example only the first bind to the source, list1, gets data. Any ideas?

Comment: <insert (possibly bad) advice to use an ORM here>

Answer (score 1):

You can do that Like following.

```
string commandText = "Select * from books where firstcondition;Select * from books where secondcondition";

        SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, datasource1);
        datasource1.Open();
        SqlDataReader myReader1 = mycommand.ExecuteReader();

 list1.DataSource = myReader1;
 list1.DataBind();

 myReader1.NextResultSet();

 list2.DataSource = myReader1;
 list2.DataBind();
```

Comment: Even better, OP would use two datasets because he doesn't need reusing, now that he's actually filtering **on database** and not on his program. Clearer to read, less confusing.